# .NET Core Code First error on nullable object

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

This is my logs table:

```
public class Logs
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool isError { 
        get {
            return this._isError.HasValue ? this._isError.Value : false;
        }
        set {
            this._isError = value;
            this.isError = value;
        } 
    }
    private bool? _isError = null;
}
```

and I don't know why when I try to make an insert, like:

```
var log = new Logs();
log.Action = "Send";
log.Controller = "Home";
log.Text = msg;
_context.logs.Add(log);
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'

And this is the object:

[image: log error]

Except that `private _isError` variable, all the database columns have a value.

Where is the error?

Comment: Side note: there is StackOverflowException in setter of `isError`.

Comment: Share your context configuration, please =)

Comment: Make sure that configuration you have not `Required` property.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your private property nullable and your public property is not?

I would remove your private property and then change your public property:

```
public bool IsError { get; set; }
```

Since you're never going to return 'null' anyway, why would you make it an option?

Edit:

I also think this will cause an endless loop of your IsError property to be set:

```
set {
        this._isError = value;
        this.isError = value;
    }
```

You're setting the public property within the public property setter.
Only setting the private property here is enough since you return the value of the private property in your getter.

This is just a side note though, I would still remove the private property and just use

```
public bool IsError { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, what’s the best way to add a default value?